# How to do unit testing on timer functions on a microcontroller

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded

I am new to the concept of unit testing, and I am currently trying to get more comfortable with it.

I have to do unit testing on a timer driver for a microcontroller written in C. Now, I heard that a unit test on a function should not depend on the outcome of another function. My problem is, how can we test a function that is supposed to stop a timer in these conditions ? Don't we need to start the timer, heck, we even need to initialize it !

I would like to know at which level we need to consider our unit test ; is it at the level of one function (in that case, we get the problem above), or is it at the level of the driver itself (in that case, we can use multiple functions of the driver in one unit test) ?

I would love to hear from more experienced people their feeling about this subject, as I feel I'm going nowhere at the moment.

Comment: as well as answer/comments below, for functionality you of course do have to test the function at least in the normal use case, but perhaps depending on the design out of that normal use case.  So normal use case is reading the time with the timer running so to prepare for that function under test (reading the time) you naturally have to boot and initialize the timer.  But if the read the time function supports detecting that the timer was not initialized then you also need to test it specifically without the timer initialized and see if it detects that correctly .

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as follows:

You can test each function independently to check that it adheres to its interface and handles out-of-bound values of parameters (if that is a requirement; the converse is that the requirement is with the caller not to call it out-of-bounds).

You can also do a code inspection on each function.

Then you can unit test the whole unit, in one way from the higher level routines: can it be called for intialization and set-up (wand here out-of-bounds conditions must be handled) and can any call-backs be called and are they called properly.

For hardware related elements you can either simulate it or create a dedicated hardware environment for the testing (test harness, test bed).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to be clear, in the first step, when testing each function independently, we only focus on how the function handles the bounds of the inputs, but we don't look at what the function **really** does, right ? Because for example, launching a timer_start without a timer_init first will not even launch the timer.

Comment: See it as two parts: testing the "outside" (interface behavior) and the "inside" (functionality). In your case part 2 cannot be done in my step 1, so you don't. But you still need to test it, hence my other steps, including a specialized testbed if necessary (and possible and budgetted and...)

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty much only one correct way to test a timer driver:

- Write a test case application that uses all functions of the driver. Leave the driver code itself completely untouched.
- Important test parameters to note/document: clock speed, clock accuracy. That is, which clock source is the timer hardware getting its clock from, how fast is it and what is the expected accuracy? You'll probably want to test the driver against a proper crystal oscillator and not some built-in RC oscillator. That way you can rule out clock inaccuracy and see what the driver latency is. Internal PLLs/FLLs in the system clock can also have a certain inaccuracy.
- In the test application, set some GPIO pins wherever you expect the timer to stop etc. Possibly from a callback function, depending on how the driver is written.
- Measure the actual time with an oscilloscope. This is mandatory, you can't test such code without one. Period.

There's not much more to it. Optionally, if you want a more in-depth test, you could include some manner of code coverage to see if all parts of the driver code are executed at some point.

Comment: I was focusing so much on the initialization aspect of the driver that I almost forgot the importance of accuracy... Thanks for reminding me of that ! I have another question : would you test only one of the timers and say that all of the other timers are in the same 'equivalence class', or would you test every single timer ?